# Does Paypal security upgrades affects subscription button?

Tags: paypal, sha256, endpoint, tls1.2, http-1.1

I have a webpage with a subscription button, on user's click it redirects to paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr.

I change the business input to my business sandbox account and change endpoint to sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr.

My sandbox buyer account appears to been working good since the balance change when test transaction is perform.

I would like to know if this test means my page meets the new Paypal security changes (TLS 1.2 and HTTP/1.1 protocols and SHA-256 and G5 certificates).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Security upgrade will not impact the subscription button. As you mentioned, you test sandbox transactions, if everything is fine in sandbox environment, you don't need to take any actions.